How to change the attributes of Django login form
My site is RTL so I need to adjust the direction of some fields to LTR (username, email, password, etc).
One of them is the Password Change form so this is what I do:
forms.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm

class CustomPasswordChangeForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['old_password'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})
        self.fields['new_password1'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})
        self.fields['new_password2'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})


views.py
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordChangeView
from accounts.forms import CustomPasswordChangeForm

class CustomPasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
    form_class = CustomPasswordChangeForm

urls.py:
path('admin/password_change', CustomPasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

That works perfectly and all 3 fields are LTR.
The other one is the Login Form so I do the same thing:
forms.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})

views.py
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from accounts.forms import CustomAuthenticationForm

class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    form_class = CustomAuthenticationForm

urls.py
path('admin/login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls,),

This time, the above code does not have any effect. Both fields are still RTL.
So why it works for password change and not for login and what's the solution for login form?

Let's start with your why question on what you are trying to achieve with your code. I believed that the CustomPasswordChangeForm you've created works because it's associated with the password change view. However, the CustomAuthenticationForm doesn't seem to have the desired effect for the login view because of the AuthenticationForm is more complex and includes additional logic for user authentication, and you are not overriding the widget properly in your form class by using the PasswordInput class which you suppose to call from your form.
Here is the updated version of your code;

  from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

    class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
        def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(request, *args, **kwargs)
            # Set the widget for the password field
            self.fields['password'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'dir': 'ltr'})


#Thus, instead of `self.fields['password'].widget.attrs.update({'dir': 'ltr'})`, we rather set the widget explicitly to a `PasswordInput` with `type="password"` as you saw above in our updated code above.




However, you can also make the above code more cleaner imo by defining the widget directly in the form field definition as I stated here, I think it is cleaner for me:
```python
class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    password = forms.CharField(
        label='Password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'dir': 'ltr'})
    )
```

Other considerations, you have to put in mind:

Ensure that your login template (registration/login.html) correctly renders the form field using {{ form.password }}. However, if you’re manually rendering the password field, make sure you’re using the correct widget. Goodluck mate


Your updated version of the form gives me this error: TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/login/.

Good, at least we are getting somewhere. Now, you have to create the template of the (authentication) login.

PS: Please verify that your login.html template exists in the registration folder. The template name should match exactly when rendering it in your views. If not, create one, as well as the login view.

For my CustomChangePasswordForm and CustomChangePasswordView I haven't created a template. I just set the form_class and it worked.
